# Como mostrar 3 DBGrid dependientes

Tags: delphi

Tengo en Delphi un programa y en la base de datos tengo una tabla de categorías de estadísticas (tiene `id` y `nombre`), con la idea de asignar a cada registro de `producto` un `id` de categoría para agruparlos.

Quiero desarrollar un formulario donde al seleccionar una categoría de estadísticas de una grilla o combo me muestre, en otra grilla, los productos en dicha lista (es decir los que tiene el `id` de esa lista en la tabla `productos`) y, por ultimo, otra grilla con los que no están asociados, para poder asociarlos.

Tengo un `TClientDataSet` y un `TDataSetProvider` junto a un `TDataSource` para la tabla de categoría de estadísticas.

Luego hice 1 `TSQLQuery` con un parametro `'id'`:

```sql
 SELECT * FROM productos WHERE Categoria_E=':id';
```

Y este otro:

```sql
 SELECT * FROM productos WHERE Categoria_E<>':id';
```

para asociarlos a las grillas; también por intermedio de un `TClientDataSet` y *provider*.

¿Esta bien asi?

Si es que si, ¿en que evento puedo asociar el valor del parámetro `id` para refrescar la grilla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es necesario utilizar las comillas dentro del SQL cuando utilizas un parámetro, pues para la capa de conexión, esta ya es una cadena de texto, a declarar el tipo del parámetro como `string`, de tal manera que tu *SQL* debiera lucir más bien como esto:

```sql
SELECT * FROM productos WHERE Categoria_E = :id;
```

Luego, suponiendo que tienes los siguientes `TClientDataSet` declarados:

- `cdsCategoria` (`select * from Categoria`)
- `cdsProductoEnCategoria` (`SELECT * FROM productos WHERE Categoria_E = :id`)
- `cdsProductosNoCategoria` (`SELECT * FROM productos WHERE coalesce(Categoria_E, '') = :id`)

Puedes declarar un método `RefrescarProductos`, así:

```delphi
procedure TMiFormulario.RefrescarProductos;
  procedure RefrescarCDS(cds: TClientDataSet);
  begin
    if cds.Active then cds.Close;
    cds.Params.ParamByName('id').AsString := cdsCategoriaidCategoria.AsString;
    cds.Open;
  end;
begin
  RefrescarCDS(cdsProductosEnCategoria);
  RefrescarCDS(cdsProductosNoCategoria);
end;
```

Y finalmente invocar este método en los eventos `OnAfterOpen` on `OnAfterScroll` del `cdsCategoria`, algo como:

```delphi
procedure TMiFormulario.cdsCategoriaAfterOpen(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RefrescarProductos;
end;
```

Comment: Gracias amigo. Me funciono a la perfeccion